# Prove that $X_t = W_t \mathbb{1}(\tau > t) + (2W_{\tau} - W_t) \mathbb{1}(\tau \le t)$ is a martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Consider $W_t$ is a standard Wiener process. Assume $\tau = \inf\{t : W_t = a\}$. Consider $X_t = W_t \mathbb{1}(\tau > t) + (2W_{\tau} - W_t) \mathbb{1}(\tau \le t)$.  We want to show that $(X_t, \mathcal{F}_t)$ is a martingale, where $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ is natural filtration of the Wiener process.

I know that it's possible to show that the process is also Wiener, but it's much more complicated (since we use strong Markov property). Here I guess the situation is much easier.

It's not hard to show that $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable and $L_1$. The major problem is to show $\mathbb{E}(X_t | F_s) = X_s$ precisely.

I tried so: consider different cases

1. $s < t < \tau$: $\mathbb{E}(W_t|F_s) = W_s$
2. $s < \tau < t$: $\mathbb{E}(2W_\tau - W_t | F_s) = \mathbb{E}(2W_\tau - 2W_s + W_s - W_t + W_s | F_s) = W_s$
3. $\tau < s < t$: $\mathbb{E}(2W_\tau - W_t| F_s) = \mathbb{E}(2W_\tau - W_s - (W_t - W_s)|F_s) = 2W_\tau - W_s$

But I guess it's not so fair to write so, since $\tau$ is random variable and for some $\omega \in \Omega$ it might be true and for others not. Any hints?

Comment: Did you mean to write $X_t = W_t \mathbb{1}(\color{red}\tau > t) + (2W_{\tau} - W_t) \mathbb{1}(\color{red}\tau \le t)$ instead?

Comment: @JoseAvilez yes! My bad. Edited.

Comment: Hint: consider the equality $E(X_t \vert \mathcal{F}_s)= E(X_t \mathbb{1}_{\tau \leq s} \vert \mathcal{F}_s )+ E(X_t  \mathbb{1}_{\tau > s } \vert \mathcal{F}_s)$

Comment: @FOE and then use that $\mathbb{1}(\tau \le s)$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable? But there are at least one problem with $\mathbb{1}(\tau > s)$, since it might be that $\mathbb{1}(s < \tau < t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the expression can be rewritten as:
$$ W_t \mathbb{1}_{\tau >s} - W_t \mathbb{1}_{t \geq \tau >s}+ (2W_{\tau}-W_t)\mathbb{1}_{\tau \leq s}+(2W_{\tau}-W_t)\mathbb{1}_{s<\tau \leq t}$$

On one hand
$$E(W_t \mathbb{1}_{\tau >s}+(2W_{\tau}-W_t)\mathbb{1}_{\tau \leq s} \vert \mathcal{F}_s)= W_s \mathbb{1}_{\tau >s} + (2W_{\tau}-W_s)\mathbb{1}_{\tau \leq s}  $$

Therefore we need to prove
$$E(- W_t \mathbb{1}_{s < \tau \leq t} +(2W_{\tau}-W_t)\mathbb{1}_{s<\tau \leq t} \vert \mathcal{F}_s)=0$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  E((2W_{\tau}-2W_t)\mathbb{1}_{s<\tau \leq t} \vert 
\mathcal{F}_s)=0$$
Which is true because $W_t-W_{\tau}$ is independant of $\mathcal{F}_s$ when $s<\tau \leq t$ and has $0$ expected value when $ \tau \leq t$

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about term $(2W_\tau - W_t)\mathbb{1}(\tau \le s) - (2W_\tau - W_t)\mathbb{1}(s < \tau \le t)$ and $W_t \mathbb{1}(\tau > s)$. Because $\{\tau > s\}$ implies $\tau < t$, hence it will be $2W_\tau - W_t$, instead of $W_s$.

Comment: It seems there should be: $W_t \mathbb{1}(t > s > \tau) + W_t \mathbb{1}(s < \tau < t) + (2W_\tau - W_t) \mathbb{1}(\tau < s < t)$

Comment: There was a mistake in the signs I just edited, , however I can not understand your statement: $\lbrace \tau >s \rbrace$ does not implies $\tau <t $

Comment: Yes, now it seems to be clear.

Comment: If you want to be more formal, the final statement (which is true and maybe not hard to see) could be proved with the Strong Markov Property and studying the distribution of the increments of the Brownian Motion.